# How do I setup the PiTFT Plus 3.5" touchscreen?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, touchscreen

[image]

How do I set up the [PiTFT Plus 3.5" touchscreen](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2441) with a Raspberry Pi 2?

Comment: Please show how you have it connected, and if you've attempted to install any drivers. There is software that needs to be installed after the LCD is connected correctly (if you're not using their custom image... specify whether you're using that as well).

Answer (score 1):

Download the ready-to-go image from here https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-3-dot-5-touch-screen-for-raspberry-pi/easy-install , flash it on a card, boot it up, and you should be ... ready-to go.

Comment: A result there is not yet loaded

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full [how to](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-3-dot-5-touch-screen-for-raspberry-pi/easy-install) but...

1) Expand filesystem using raspi config
2) Install new kernel:

```
curl -SLs https://apt.adafruit.com/add-pin | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install -y raspberrypi-bootloader adafruit-pitft-helper raspberrypi-kernel
```

3)Enable and configure pi-tft:

```
sudo adafruit-pitft-helper -t 35r
```

4) reboot

```
sudo reboot
```